# JavaScript вывод названия позиции с помощью функции

Tags: javascript

есть код на JS. В js "шарю" очень плохо. Сейчас при задействовании функции добавляется html код с названием ({ return_value: "name" }), но надо, чтобы также выходила сумма ("value"). Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать? Буду очень признателен. Цельный код приложил

```
    this.live_summary_update = function(form_id) {
    if (this.form_vars[form_id].live_summary_enabled == 0) return;

    var out = "";

    $.each(ezfc_vars.element_vars[form_id], function(i, element) {
        if (typeof element["current_value"] === "undefined" || element.show_in_live_summary == 0) return;

        var current_value = $.trim(element.current_value);

        if (typeof element["options"] !== "undefined") {
            current_value = _this.get_value_from_element(null, element.id, true, null, { return_value: "name" });

            if (current_value == 0) return;
        }
        else if (typeof element["current_value_formatted"] !== "undefined") {
            current_value = element.current_value_formatted;
        }

        if (current_value == "" || current_value == 0) return;

        if (typeof current_value === "object") {
            current_value = "<ul class='ezfc-live-summary-list'><li class='ezfc-live-summary-list-item'>" + current_value.join("</li><li class='ezfc-live-summary-list-item'>") + "</li></ul>";
        }

        out += "<div class='ezfc-live-summary-item'><div class='ezfc-live-summary-item-name'>" + element.label + "<span class='ezfc-live-summary-item-separator'></span></div><div class='ezfc-live-summary-item-value'>" + current_value + "</div></div>";
    });

    $("#ezfc-live-summary-" + form_id).html(out);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. На выходе получился такой код.

```
    this.live_summary_update = function(form_id) {
    if (this.form_vars[form_id].live_summary_enabled == 0) return;

    var out = "";

    $.each(ezfc_vars.element_vars[form_id], function(i, element) {
        if (typeof element["current_value"] === "undefined" || element.show_in_live_summary == 0) return;

        var current_value = $.trim(element.current_value);

        if (typeof element["options"] !== "undefined") {
            current_value = _this.get_value_from_element(null, element.id, true, null, { return_value: "name"});

            if (current_value == 0) return;
        }
        else if (typeof element["current_value_formatted"] !== "undefined") {
            current_value = element.current_value_formatted;
        }

        if (current_value == "" || current_value == 0) return;

        if (typeof current_value === "object") {
            current_value = "<ul class='ezfc-live-summary-list'><li class='ezfc-live-summary-list-item'>" + current_value.join("</li><li class='ezfc-live-summary-list-item'>") + "</li></ul>";
        }
            /****/
                    var current_value2 = $.trim(element.current_value2);

        if (typeof element["options"] !== "undefined") {
            current_value2 = _this.get_value_from_element(null, element.id, true, null, { return_value: "value" });

            if (current_value2 == 0) return;
        }
        else if (typeof element["current_value_formatted"] !== "undefined") {
            current_value2 = element.current_value2_formatted;
        }

        if (current_value2 == "" || current_value2 == 0) return;

        if (typeof current_value2 === "object") {
            current_value2 = "<ul class='ezfc-live-summary-list'><li class='ezfc-live-summary-list-item'>" + current_value2.join("</li><li class='ezfc-live-summary-list-item'>") + "</li></ul>";
        }
            /****/

        out += "<div class='ezfc-live-summary-item'><div class='ezfc-live-summary-item-name'>" + element.label + "<span class='ezfc-live-summary-item-separator'></span></div><div class='ezfc-live-summary-item-value'>" + current_value + "<div class='live-summary-value'>" + current_value2 + "</div>" + "</div></div>";
    });

    $("#ezfc-live-summary-" + form_id).html(out);
};
```